# How to display 2 grid of ag-grid on the same component

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid

Like I'm trying to do a component with 2 tables.

```
HTML.

<div class="d-flex w-100 d-lg-inline">
    <div class="grid_container width-45 d-flex d-lg-inline-flex">
        <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-material" 
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [animateRows]="true" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
                    [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" rowSelection="single" 
                    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" (columnResized)="onColumnResized($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
    
<div class="grid_container width-45 d-flex d-lg-inline-flex">
        <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" class="ag-theme-material" 
                  [columnDefs]="columnDefs2" [animateRows]="true" (gridReady)="onGridReady2($event)" 
                  [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" rowSelection="single" 
                  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" (columnResized)="onColumnResized($event)">
        </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

TS

```
  this.columnDefs = [
    {headerName: res.TAGS_ASOCIADOS , field: 'nombreTag', width: 500, maxWidth: 650, minWidth: 300},
   {headerName: res.SISTEMA , field: 'indSistema' , maxWidth: 200, minWidth: 100, headerClass: 'grid_header-center', cellClass: 'text-center'},

  ];
  this.columnDefs2 = [
    {headerName: res.TAGS_DISPONIBLES, field: 'nombre', width: 500, maxWidth: 650, minWidth: 300},
    {headerName: res.SISTEMA, field: 'tagDelSistema', maxWidth: 200, minWidth: 100, cellRenderer: 'checkboxRenderer', headerClass: 'grid_header-center', cellClass: 'text-center'},
  ];
```

---

```
  onGridReady(params) { 
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnapi;
    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.tagListAsociados);
  }

  onGridReady2(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnapi;
    this.gridApi.setRowData(this.tagList);
  }
```

I can see correctly the different headers. But the problem came when I try to display data into the tabled.
My second table display data, but the first table didn't work.

I want something like this.

[image]

Comment: Your code looks fine. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-oo8rwh) is a StackBlitz of your code with row data displaying correctly.

Comment: Oh thank you Viqas. I think my problem is the way that i take my data. maybe an async problem, because it works when I use a debugger. I will investigate about this. 

But really thanks ! :)